# Call servlet on hyperlink

Tags: jsp, servlets, hyperlink

When I click the log out button, request is re-directed to a servlet. However it doesn't seem to work fine. I did map the servlet at web.xml.

The error that I am getting is

> **The requested resource (/LogoutServlet) is not available.**

Below are my codes.

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
   <display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlet.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**At JSP**

```
<a href="/LogoutServlet">Log Off</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="/LogoutServlet">Log Off</a>`

The URL should not start with a forward slash `/` . You need to understand this that whenever you put a forward slash on some URL, it will be re-directed to the root of the server ( not the application) , in reality we don't want this.

With the above link, the URL in the browser will be like `http://somehost:port/LogoutServlet` while it should've been something like `http://somehost:port/youApplicationContext/../LogoutServlet`.

To fix this issue , simple edit your href to look like `<a href="LogoutServlet">Log Off</a>` (without the forward slash)